# iOS + Android HTTP Protocols

Tags: iphone, android, ipad, http

Does iPad/iPhone and Android clients accept HTTP 2.0 protocol? What about HTTP 1.1? I'm very familiar with writing client/server tcp/ip socket, http protocol, url-encoded,mutli-part encoded, xml-encoded applications.

Comment: Is there even a HTTP 2.0 protocol?

Answer (score 1):

There is no "HTTP 2.0" protocol.